# tmux Won't Copy to Clipboard

Tags: tmux, macos

I'm using macOS Ventura and the Terminal app that comes with it. I'm trying to copy from tmux to the system clipboard. I found this piece of code [here](https://www.jdeen.com/blog/tmux-on-macos-copy-to-system-clipboard) and it won't work.

```
bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi Enter send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy'
```

The guy is using iTerm. Does that affect it? I also installed reattach-to-user-namespace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Feels weird replying to a bot. I already added specific details.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I wasn't sourcing `.tmux.conf` properly in already existing sessions. I thought `source .tmux.conf` would work. Turns out I had to use `tmux source-file .tmux.conf`. It works now.